# Iterator on binary tree compilation error

Tags: c++, iterator, binary-tree

I get the following compilation error:

> error: invalid conversion from 'const IntervalST*' to 'IntervalST*' [-fpermissive]

when I compile my code.
The code is quite big but here are the relevant parts:

the class IntervalST:

```
template <class Key> class intervalST_const_iterator;

template <class Key> class IntervalST
{
private:
    Interval<Key> *root;

    //friend class intervalST_const_iterator<Key>;//allow the iterator class to access the private section of intervalST

    bool isRed(Interval<Key> *interval);
    Interval<Key> *rotateLeft(Interval<Key> *h);
    Interval<Key> *rotateRight(Interval<Key> *h);
    Interval<Key> *put(Interval<Key> *h,Key lo, Key hi, Key val);
    Interval<Key> *moveRedLeft(Interval<Key> *h);
    Interval<Key> *moveRedRight(Interval<Key> *h);
    Interval<Key> *deleteMin(Interval<Key> *h, Key hi);
    Interval<Key> *balance(Interval<Key> *h);
    Interval<Key> *remove(Interval<Key> *h, Key lo, Key hi);
    Interval<Key> *min(Interval<Key> *h);
    Interval<Key> *addDuplicate(Interval<Key> *h, Key hi);
    Interval<Key> *removeDuplicate(Interval<Key> *h, Key low, Key hi);
    Interval<Key> *getPointerToKey(Key low);

    void flipColors(Interval<Key> *h);
    void destroy(Interval<Key> *h);
    void printTree(Interval<Key> *h, int indent);
    Key maxVal(Interval<Key> *h);
    int size(Interval<Key> *h);
    bool isBST(Interval<Key> *x, Key min, Key max);
    inline bool isBST(){return isBST(root,0,0);}
    bool isSizeConsistent(Interval<Key> *x);
    inline bool isSizeConsistent(){return isSizeConsistent(root);}
    bool is23(Interval<Key> *x);
    inline bool is23(){return is23(root);}
    bool isBalanced();
    bool isBalanced(Interval<Key> *x,int black);
    int getKeySize(Key low);
    int compare(Key a, Key b);

public:

    //don't forget to build the constructor
    //and overload the =equal operator
    typedef intervalST_const_iterator<Key> const_iterator;//const iterator on a tree


    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator end() const;

    IntervalST():root(NULL){};
    ~IntervalST();
    void remove(Key lo, Key hi);
    void put(Key lo, Key hi);
    inline int size(){return size(root);}
    inline bool isEmpty(){return root == NULL;}
    void print(int indent = 0);
    void check();


};
```

**The compiler is complaining on the implementation of the *begin()* method of the class *IntervalST***

*begin()* and *end()* method:

```
template <typename Key> typename IntervalST<Key>::const_iterator IntervalST<Key>::begin() const
{
return const_iterator(root,this);//<-----------code complaining here
}

template <typename Key> typename IntervalST<Key>::const_iterator IntervalST<Key>::end() const
{
return const_iterator(NULL,this);
}
```

here is the iterator class:

```
template <class Key> class intervalST_const_iterator
{
//friend class IntervalST<Key>;

private:
    Interval<Key> *interval;
    IntervalST<Key> *tree;

public:
    intervalST_const_iterator(Interval<Key> *p, IntervalST<Key> *t): interval(p), tree(t){}
    bool operator != (const intervalST_const_iterator & other) const
    {
        return this->interval != other.interval;
    }
    bool operator == (const intervalST_const_iterator & other) const
    {
        return this->interval == other.interval;
    }
    Interval<Key> operator *() const
    {
        return *(this->interval);
    }
    intervalST_const_iterator<Key> & left() const
    {
        return (interval = interval->left);
    }
    intervalST_const_iterator<Key> & right() const
    {
        return (interval = interval->right);
    }
};
```

Why is this happening? and how to solve it?
Surprisingly the implementation of the *end()* method is almost the same as the implementation
of the *begin()* method.
thanks for your help

Comment: `this` is `const` in the context of `begin()` (it must be, as the member is `const`), yet you're passing it as non-const `IntervalST<Key> *` to the iterator constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your member function `Interval<Key>::begin()`, is marked `const`, so any use of `this` must also be `const`. In this case, the constructor for your iterator class accepts pointers to non-const `Interval<Key>` objects, so passing `this` here is not allowed. You should add the `const` keyword to all the `Interval<Key>` pointers in your `intervalST_const_iterator` class, starting with the constructor arguments.

For similar reasons, your `left()` and `right()` member functions of `intervalST_const_iterator` will also fail to compile because they too are marked const, yet they modify the `interval` field of the iterator.

Note that in the conventions of the C++ template library, a `const_iterator` is not itself constant, but the container object it iterates over is constant. As opposed to a non-constant `iterator` that allows you to add/remove/modify elements of the container. Both const/non-const iterators must be themselves mutable so you can step them through each element.

*Update:* In your iterator class, your member variables must be constant:

```
const Interval<Key> *interval;
const IntervalST<Key> *tree;
```

Then, the iterator's member functions must also use constant interval pointers:

```
intervalST_const_iterator(const Interval<Key> *p, const IntervalST<Key> *t)
const Interval<Key> operator *() const
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I understand what you mean. But how to proceed here? I'd like to define this iterator in order to traverse the tree without being able to modify the tree - I have no idea how to do it correctly. Can you explain me how to do it by editing your answer - thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your `intervalST_const_iterator` class constructor expects non const pointers to `Interval<Key>` and `IntervalST<Key>`:

```
intervalST_const_iterator(Interval<Key> *p, IntervalST<Key> *t);
```

In const method of `IntervalST`you try to create intervalST_const_iterator:

```
template <typename Key> typename IntervalST<Key>::const_iterator IntervalST<Key>::begin() const
{
   return const_iterator(root,this);//<-----------code complaining here
}
```

`this` has type `const IntervalST *` but you try to pass it as `IntervalST *` as constructor of `intervalST_const_iterator` expects.